# Email is send but not received

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email, send

I have tested this script and ajax is sending data so this variables are good. I have echo every one of them, they are working fine... When I send email I get success so its working? But im not getting anything on my mail?

```
<?php

    // save input values
    $title = $_POST['var1'];
    $email = $_POST['var2'];
    $msg = $_POST['var3'];

    // setup email info
    $to      = "wersastudio@gmail.com";
    $subject = $title;
    $txt     = $msg;
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    // send email
    $send = mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);

    // check if email is send or not
    if ( $send ) {
        echo 'success';
    }else {
        echo 'error';
    }
?>
```

Comment: <?php

    // save input values
    $title = $_POST['var1'];
    $email = $_POST['var2'];
    $msg = $_POST['var3'];
    
    // setup email info
    $to      = "wersastudio@gmail.com";
    $subject = $title;
    $txt     = $msg;
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    // send email
    $send = mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
    
    // check if email is send or not
    if ( $send ) {
        echo 'success';
    }else {
        echo 'error';
    }
?>

Comment: Sorry for this dont know why the webpage didnt show my php so I have send it in comment above.

Comment: You don't need `Reply-to` if it's the same as `From`.

Comment: Check your server's mail log to see if the mail was sent. It could also be getting filtered as spam.

Comment: Is this running on a local server such as XAMPP, or a cloud based server? If you're not on a local environment, you'll need to set the reply to, and from email addresses to something at your own domain (e.g. noreply@mydomain.com). If it is a local server, you probably need to setup an email server such as sendmail. XAMPP and WAMP do not do this by default.